# change default page in war file

Tags: java, netbeans, war

I have created a war file for my web application.I deployed it on Tomcat,it is working fine. My question is that if I have 3 jsp files like index.jsp,one.jsp,two.jsp, what if I want to run one.jsp first(not index.jsp) when I am running war file. Presently index.jsp is running primarily.I am using netbeans,is there any option in netbeans???

Comment: Previously I used to get web.xml under web-inf in netbeans,but for the new application I am not getting web.xml,instead this is formed above the servlet class:@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})...I have 2 applications now,one with web.xml and other without web.xml.How can it be posssible??? –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can set that in web.xml in the WEB-INF folder by setting the welcome-file-list

normally it looks like

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

change it to

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>one.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thank you..Previously I used to get web.xml under web-inf in netbeans,but for the new application I am not getting web.xml,instead this is formed above the servlet class:@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})...I have 2 applications now,one with web.xml and other without web.xml.How can it be posssible???

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about since now you're mentioning a second web application and I thought I was answering the posted question. If this answer solves the problem you had asked about then please accpet the answer and post another question pertaining to the second web application.

Comment: But I have a problem with web.xml,I manually created it..Generally it will be formed automatically in netbeans..Any solution??